# compare two columns in excel doesn't work?

Tags: excel, if-statement, compare, persian

I have two excat rows but comparing them returns false by using this formula

```
=if(A1=B1,"True","False")
```

some rows

A1     |     B1

```
ڕێککەوتنێکی خراپ    ڕێككەوتنێكی خراپ
شتێک کە دەستکەوتنی مسۆگەر نەبێت شتێك كە دەستكەوتنی مسۆگەر نەبێت
شتێکی دەستکەوتوو    شتێكی دەستكەوتوو
ڕووداوێکی نەهات ڕووداوێكی نەهات
کتومت لە بابی دەچێ لە ڕەووشت و ڕووخساردا    كتومت لە بابی دەچێ لە ڕەووشت و ڕووخساردا
ئاهەنگێک کە خەڵک خۆیانی بۆ دەگۆڕن و جلوبەرگی سەیر لەبەردەکەن    ئاهەنگێك كە خەڵك خۆیانی بۆ دەگۆڕن و جلوبەرگی سەیر لەبەردەكەن
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OylaH.png

Comment: First, you are comparing CELLS, not rows. Secondly, post an example in ENGLISH so your potential target advisors gets wider. Third, try to deploy in cells A1 and B1 the string "WE ARE THE SAME" and see what your formula says.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simple, although the cells where excatly looking the same but the characters were different, so I used find and replace to replace the the characters the way I wanted.